# A concrete example of a Hermitian positive definite matrix with complex numbers?

Tags: linear-algebra

I hope someone could provide an example of a Hermitian positive definite matrix with complex numbers in it. I searched the internet and all I can find are symmetric ones with only real values. Many thanks!

Comment: The diagonal will always contain real numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35239/how-is-it-shown-that-a-hermitian-matrix-will-be-positive-definite?rq=1): 
$$\left( \begin{array}{cc} 2 & i
 \\ -i & 2\\ \end{array} \right)$$

Because the sum of positive definite matrices is also positive definite we have also, say:

$$\left( \begin{array}{cc} 2 & i
 \\ -i & 2\\ \end{array} \right)
+\left( \begin{array}{cc} 3 & 1
 \\ 1 & 2\\ \end{array} \right)=
\left( \begin{array}{cc} 5 & 1+i
 \\ 1-i & 4\\ \end{array} \right)
$$

As pointed out in a comment, you cannot have all entries complex, as the elements in the diagonal must be real.

Answer (score 4):

Well, real numbers *are* complex.

One can cook up an example using the following [fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix):

> If a square matrix ${\displaystyle A}$ equals the multiplication of a matrix and its conjugate transpose, that is, ${\displaystyle A=BB^{H}}$, then $A$ is a Hermitian positive semi-definite matrix. Furthermore, if $B$ is row full-rank, then $A$ is positive definite.

Consider for instance taking
$$B=
\begin{pmatrix}
1&i\\
i&2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and let $A=BB^H$.

Comment: It is $-i$ on the second row or on the second column.

Comment: @Daniel No. $B$ does not need to be Hermitian.

Comment: I am sorry. I thought your example was B. Now I see that your example is $BB^H$.

Comment: @Daniel: I agree that it was confusing. Edited it.